# How do you describe a test that puts you in one of a number of grades (specifying the grade)?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If a test puts you in a particular grade (result), how is it described? For example, "Five tier graded test"? The test might be a language test and the results might be A, B, C, D, E.

*Please note that I would like to include how many grades there are in this phrase.*

Comment: What is wrong with *graded*?

Comment: @MattЭллен, I would like to include the number of grades (amended question).

Answer (score 2):

It is a *test with five outcomes.* If you want, you can call it a *five-outcome test.* I don't think there's a better word for this, because such a word wouldn't be needed very often.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those that's going to vary quite a bit based on which English dialect you're speaking and what the purpose of the test is, but here are a few options:

- A *placement* test
- A *qualification* test
- An *evaluation*
- An *assessment*

Comment: None of those include the number of possible grades.

Answer (score 0):

A test of any kind by default puts you in one of two grades, pass or fail. Additionally it's not unexpected that further grading would occur, especially in academic tests. The point being that most of the time it's not even regularly or formally mentioned but simply assumed. In any case a "five grade test" or a "test graded from A to F" is good enough for most circumstances.